# Use default Craft error/exception layout in Plugin

Tags: plugin-development

Is it possible for me to use the default Craft error-handling/exception-throwing/debug-showing template layout for my own plugin? Let's say something goes wrong and I want to show that to the user in the same style as any other "code related error" for my Plugin.

Could/how would I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, then you get that behavior by default.

If you:

```
throw new \Exception('Uh oh.');
```

Then you'll get the same error handling layout and logic that Craft uses.

You can [read here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/478/render-generic-message-error-template-from-plugin/483#483) for more information on how that works.

Comment: ... I don't even know why I just didn't try this. Cheers Brad :)

Comment: Minor note: `throw new Exception('Uh oh.');` might not work if you're inside your own class that extends something else. Add a backslash before Exception to read from "root". `throw new \Exception('Uh oh.');`