# How to set a response 200 from a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, json

I’ve tried `HeaderHelper::setHeader(array('code' => 200))` without success.

Comment: Can you give a little more context/code examples about what you're trying to do?  Craft will do some automatic header response code setting depending on the type of request it is.

Comment: I was trying to set it as a response to a web hook. 200 for a successful function, or appropriate respone if something went wrong.

Comment: This is maybe more appropriate: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/478/render-generic-message-error-template-from-plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12018482/684) for various methods of setting the response code depending on what version of PHP and which PHP module you're running.